# Difference between we all and we are all

Tags: word-order, determiners

What is the difference between the given two sentences?

> We all are teenagers.
>
> We are all teenagers.

Comment: The first version is "marked" - it wouldn't normally be used except in poetic or other "florid language" contexts.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning between your two example sentences.
In fact a shortened form of

> **you all**

is part of the *southern regional accent* in the US

> **ya'll**
>
> **Ya'll hurry back!**
>   *All of you come back soon!*

Answer (score 1):

We are all teenagers.

We all are teenagers.

All of us are teenagers.

The sentences are all grammatical; there's no difference in meaning.

The "are" is a  be verb. . When "all" refers to the subject of a clause, we usually put it after the be verb. So the first sentence is  more idiomatic and common.